# Cannot get proper exit code from $?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a backup bash script, and organize it as a set of several .sh files (each of them executing one function) that are called from the main .sh file (like libraries in any conventional PL). One of them is a logging script that is to take an exit code of the previously executed command and if it succeeds the script logs one message, and if it doesn't - logs another.

However, if I check $? within the logging script, I always get 0 code regardless of the previous command's result in the main script. As far as I understand the process, calling the script from an outer file makes it being executed in a different subshell that has $? with 0 value as nothing failed within that very subshell.

```
#main.sh:

command; log.sh "message" "error"
```

```
#log.sh:

if [ "${?}" -eq "0" ]; then
  printf "${1}\n" >> main.log
else
  printf "${2}\n" >> main.log
fi
```

The $? is always 0, so it always logs a success message. How do I get the actual exit code of the "command" above?

I might store it in some file and read the file in the beginning of the log.sh, but I feel there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
command; log.sh "message" "error"
```

with

```
command; log.sh "message" "error" "$?"
```

and

```
if [ "${?}" -eq "0" ]; then
```

with

```
if [ "$3" -eq "0" ]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by you, since `log.sh` is a script, it executes in a separate shell and hence `$?` of the caller is not visible to it. When a script starts, `$?` is 0 initially.

You can wrap your logging functionality into a function so that `$?` is visible to it:

```
log() {
    if [ "${?}" -eq "0" ]; then
      printf "${1}\n" >> main.log
    else
      printf "${2}\n" >> main.log
    fi
}
```

But it is better to pass `$?` explicitly as suggested by [@cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028623/6862601).

---

You may want to take a look at the logging and error handling functionality implemented here:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation provided, this is very helpful, as well as the link. The point of implementation functions in outer files was to make them reusable with other scripts.

Comment: You can have your function in a separate file and `source` it into every script that needs it.  That's how shell libraries work.